# Python sphinx autosummary error: "Unknown directive type "autosummary""

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a sphinx document and when I include the following lines:

```
.. currentmodule:: myMod

.. autosummary::

  MyClass
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: Unknown directive type "autosummary".
```

Yet, autosummary is available since version 0.6, and I use Sphinx 1.1.3.

What could potentially cause the problem?
Thanks!

EDIT: To make it a bit more clear I am talking about python-sphinx, the documentation tool.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`sphinx.ext.autosummary`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html#module-sphinx.ext.autosummary) is a [Sphinx extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/index.html). In order to use the extension, you must add its name to the [`extensions`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-extensions) configuration variable in conf.py:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autosummary', ...]
```

Comment: It is a bit surprising that autosummary is not part of the autodoc extension and that both have to be listed